# VB.Net UI is missing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to make a Vb.Net application.
In short, I added DotNetBar RibbonControl with some RibbonItems on it as my menu.
What happened is one of my tab is suddenly missing along with all the buttons in it.
I have searched for it on my Document Outline still no luck.

But what even more odd is, when I tried to recreate it with the same name, it shows an Alert "Property value is not valid" with message "The name AppPOButton is already in use by another component".

When I checked it on the form's Designer I do found this lines:

```
Me.AppPOButton = New DevComponents.DotNetBar.ButtonItem()
```

and

```
        'AppPOButton
    '
    Me.AppPOButton.ButtonStyle = DevComponents.DotNetBar.eButtonStyle.ImageAndText
    Me.AppPOButton.Image = Global.ProjectBMT.My.Resources.Resources.approval
    Me.AppPOButton.ImageFixedSize = New System.Drawing.Size(40, 40)
    Me.AppPOButton.ImagePosition = DevComponents.DotNetBar.eImagePosition.Top
    Me.AppPOButton.Name = "AppPOButton"
    Me.AppPOButton.SubItemsExpandWidth = 14
    Me.AppPOButton.Text = "Approve"
    Me.AppPOButton.Visible = False
```

and

```
    Friend WithEvents AppPOButton As DevComponents.DotNetBar.ButtonItem
```

Is there anyone can explain why this is happening?
Thank you

Comment: This could be a render problem. You can try to set fixed positions to yours controls somewhere. Maybe a control forced the other to move away from there positon and can not be set on the page.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: @HansPassant Well I think that's the most possible solution, since I've been trying to find with no luck. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is weird itself, but it's not a problem actually, All the Ribbon style works on "Containers", if you check your ribbon control and click the left-upper button will see these little arrows that move four containers, these objects hold the buttons, images and other controls. Within your design window in the right panel (Properties) you can still see the names of the controls you "lost" when you deleted your tab, wich is also a container.

Steps:

1. Add a container within your design view and Dock it into the Ribbon control Form.
2. Click on the uppper right boton (Right Arrow) and select "Layout Ribbon", this will adjust the lenght and hight of the controls conatained.
3. Add the tab that will contain all the controls you have.

The fact that they are still in the designer form is the prove that they still exist, This behavior is just a glitch in the position and order of the controls set above your form ;-)